# Connect to iTunes to Use Push Notifications

Tags: ios, itunes

We have a major update to our app that just came out and we have one user that continuously gets this alert:

Title: Connect to iTunes to Use Push Notifications

Message:  notifications may include alerts, sound and icon badges.

The user taps OK, and it just pops back up not allowing the user to use the app.  The user is connected to iTunes and is receiving notifications from other third-party apps.  The user has restarted several times, uninstalled and re-installed the app from the app store several times as well.

iPhone 5 running 6.0.1

Googling turns up that this is a problem with jailbroken devices, but this user's is not.

Has anyone else run into this issue at all?

Answer (score 5):

This occurs if the user's device is missing an authentication token.  It can sometimes be resolved by:

1. Connect device to computer & open iTunes
2. Make sure you are connected to the Internet & the iTunes store will load
3. Sync the iOS device

However, if other apps are working, the user probably has an expired authentication token (the iPhone was probably used with someone else's Apple ID or SIM card, and Apple is avoiding sending it someone else's push notifications.)  In this case the only resolution is to do a clean restore of the iPhone.

**Update**: for reference, here's [a somewhat related Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3305) on the topic

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any first-hand experience with this issue, but it doesn't sound like it's a problem with your code. See [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20514878#20514878) and 
 [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3394511?start=30&tstart=0).

It's most likely a problem with the user's phone or Apple ID, especially given that only one user is reporting the issue. Advise the user to do a backup/restore using iTunes or iCloud, and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: I've asked the user to do that, but he is hesitant.  Another interesting note on this is that he cannot get TestFlight to work either.  This suggests to me that this new iPhone 5 device was restored with a bad backup or something else is corrupt in the setup of the new device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the iphone in Tethered jailbreaking, then this problem usually occurs with the app that tries to listen for push notification. To solve this just

open up your RedSnow select your IPSW
and press just boot option.

This work for me and provide a great relief.